# Java & Twitter4j - searching for all tweets/ random tweets

Tags: java, api, twitter4j, tweets

I am currently working on this code. I managed to get the tweets with particular search term for example - "coffee" and showing all the tweets that contain the word coffee.

```
            Query query = new Query(term); // Search for tweets that

            q.setCount(100); // How many tweets, max, to
                                            // retrieve
            q.resultType(Query.MIXED);// Get all tweets
```

But my question is, is it possible to search all tweets, or random tweets rather than constraining my search to a specific search term like the above - coffee? 
This is because, I want to get random one word tweets from all of the tweets.
In one of my methods, I have code where I say to only fetch one word tweets.

```
                    for (Status s : r.getTweets()) // Loop through all the tweets...
            {
                totalTweets++;
                if (maxID == -1 || s.getId() < maxID) {
                    maxID = s.getId();
                }

                String tweets = getTweet(s.getText());
                String delimeter = " ";
                String tweetwords[] = tweets.split(delimeter);
                if (tweetwords.length == 1) {
                    twitterFeeds.add(tweets);
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Consider using [Twitter's hosebird](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) which is a client for the streaming api. You can get pretty far using their example, just use the sample stream and don't specify any track terms.

Answer (score 0):

Use twitter's sample stream and check if the tweet has only one word.

Example: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java

(Uses twitter4j).

Make changes like this:

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
    /*.................................
    Your code here
    */                      
}
```